# Use case of OPTIONS, TRACE and HEAD Request Method

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

There are [RequestMethod](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMethod.html) named `OPTIONS`, `TRACE` and `HEAD`.

To use these methods, I could not see any mapping like [@DeleteMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/DeleteMapping.html), [@GetMapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/GetMapping.html), etc...

Generally, we use `GET` calls to fetch data. So, still not clear **"How to define these mappings and what exactly are the use cases"?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use them as you can use the others.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
```

@GetMapping and other related annotations are just annotations annotated with these request methods. For example:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @interface GetMapping
```

Usage:

OPTIONS is useful to get allowed methods to an endpoint. If you create a public api, developers whose are using your api can retrieve them, create stubs to them depending on the answer etc...

You can use TRACE for testing. For example, because it is handled by the webserver, it can pass throught proxies etc, and the response will contains the headers added by those.
Be careful, it may retrieves sensitive informations in production.

HEAD just gives back the header of the request, but without body data. Imagine you send a GET for a large file, GET will start to download instantly. With HEAD, you can check the size, before you send a GET request, so you can make decisions before start an operation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please elaborate about TRACE?

Comment: Trace is echoing the http request back as response. So imagine that you have a proxy between the application and the users. The proxy may add fields to the header (for example correlation id...) or forward the request to a specific server (load balancing). This all (can) add informations to the http header. So these all will be packed into a response, and send back to the client. In production it may cause security vulnerable. But it is useful to diagnostic purposes.

Answer (score 9):

> OPTIONS, TRACE and HEAD are used to retrieve resource meta data
>   information. They are also called idempotent as invoking multiple
>   requests will not have any write operation on server/resource.

**OPTIONS** : This method is used by the client to find out the HTTP methods and other options supported by a server/resource.

Sample Code :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/employees", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public class EmployeeRESTController 
{
     @RequestMapping(value="/employee/{id}", method = RequestMethod.OPTIONS)
     ResponseEntity<?> collectionOptions() 
     {
          return ResponseEntity
                  .ok()
                  .allow(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST, HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                  .build();
     }
```

}

```
Try : HTTP OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/api/rest/employees/employee/1
```

---

**TRACE** : This method is basically used to echo/debug web server connections and the response sent back to the user/requester, can be used for debugging purpose.

However, An unprivileged user may be able to abuse the HTTP TRACE functionality to gain access to sensitive information in HTTP headers when making HTTP requests.

So, Ideally it's good to disable this method, unless needed.

```
Try : curl -v -X TRACE http://www.yourserver.com
```

---

**HEAD** : This method is functionally similar to GET, except for the fact that the server replies with response line and headers, but no entity-body.

Example : if GET /users returns a list of users, then HEAD /users will make the same request but won't get back the list of users.

```
Try : curl -I http://www.yourserver.com
```